# How to create State & district level map in using GADM and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cartography

I am using **Covid data** & looking to plot **State & district** level Indian data on `map`.

I have **State, District Name** of India along with Cases but do not have needed **lat, long** for them.

I came across this so post [How to map an Indian state with districts in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706542/how-to-map-an-indian-state-with-districts-in-r)

and tried `raster::getData("GADM", country = "India", level = 2) %>% as_tibble()` but this doesn't work as it doesnt have **lat,lon, shapefile** etc.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

state_level_map <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "India", level = 1) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 == "Rajasthan") %>% 
  fortify() 

  ggplot() +
  geom_map(data= state_level_map, map = state_level_map, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id, group = group))
```

I am new to **spatial data / maps** and not sure how exactly I can proceed in this situation. Is it possible to get lat, lon, shapefile etc. for State/districts name's info from any r packages or the only way is to manually google them for lat,lon ?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Use `sf` for that.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)

state_level_map <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "India", level = 1) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  filter(NAME_1 == "Rajasthan")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = state_level_map)
```

[image]

you can then easily use `aes()` to change your aesthetics of the ggplot as you normally would using variables.

`sf` uses a dataframe-like notation that incorporates both attribute data as well as geometries into a single and easy to use dataframe. just have a look at `print(state_level_map)`. That is, you could join data using district names to augment you attributes and visualize them through `aes(color = yourjoinedvar)`.

Comment: that's fabulous. Have been searching alot but wasn't able to find a simple solution as this one. Really really Appreciate your help :))